# Argos Simulators Installation Error

Tags: dpkg, debian

I am trying to install Argos simulator which is a robotics simulator. But i am getting the following error

```
sudo dpkg -i argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta56.deb                        

dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta56.deb': No such file or directory
```

This is the link to the simulators website installation guide
https://www.argos-sim.info/core.php

Can someone please help me with this its urgent. The installation command used as mentioned on the above link is

```
sudo dpkg -i argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta56.deb
```

But i get the above mentioned error.

UPDATE:
I did download the file Debian file but still getting the following error

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/yishu/Downloads/argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta56.deb 

dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/home/yishu/Downloads/argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta56.deb': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use the full /path/to/the/file.deb. You current working directory happens to different than the directory that the .deb file is located in. That's why the system cannot find the .deb - it's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Have you downloaded the DEB file from https://drive.google.com/open?id=13ny9d72ahv-5jgFS5HqacWfwSXpwO3Mf  which is the link provided at https://www.argos-sim.info/core.php? If not, please do that now. Once download completes you can run sudo dpkg -i /path/to/argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta56.deb

Comment: I've done that as well but still facing the above mentioned error in the Update portion of the post. I am new to linux and thus don't know a lot about it. So it would be really helpful if you could look into this problem.